# Is it possible to send JSONArray instead of JSONObject via POST?

Tags: java, android, json, http, post

Most of the answers on SO on the subject revolve around sending all your data inside one JSONObject, with the JSONArrays inside.

I would like to do the opposite, if possible.

Here's some code:

```
    JSONObject winnerJSONObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject loserJSONObject = new JSONObject();

try{
            winnerJSONObject.put(Columns.ID.toString(), winner.getId());
            winnerJSONObject.put(Columns.NAME.toString(), winner.getName());
            winnerJSONObject.put(Columns.SCORE.toString(),winner.getScore());
            winnerJSONObject.put(Columns.WINS.toString(), winner.getWins());
            winnerJSONObject.put(Columns.LOSSES.toString(), winner.getLosses());
            winnerJSONObject.put(Columns.MAX_SCORE.toString(),winner.getMaxScore());
            winnerJSONObject.put(Columns.MIN_SCORE.toString(),winner.getMinScore());

            loserJSONObject.put(Columns.ID.toString(), loser.getId());
            loserJSONObject.put(Columns.NAME.toString(), loser.getName());
            loserJSONObject.put(Columns.SCORE.toString(),loser.getScore());
            loserJSONObject.put(Columns.WINS.toString(),loser.getWins());
            loserJSONObject.put(Columns.LOSSES.toString(),loser.getLosses());
            loserJSONObject.put(Columns.MAX_SCORE.toString(),loser.getMaxScore());
            loserJSONObject.put(Columns.MIN_SCORE.toString(),loser.getMinScore());
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace(); 
}


    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

    try {
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonArray.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.put(winnerJSONObject);
    jsonArray.put(loserJSONObject);
```

Why is this a wrong approach?

Comment: I don't think this should be any problem. Did you try it? Are you getting any error??

Comment: I did not try it, because

1: I read people saying it shouldn't be done like that (none of them explained why)
2: I don't know how to get to each JSONObject in PHP after using json_decode (was previously using BasicNameValuePair<T> instead of json)

Comment: Of course we shouldn't. But if you want you can do that. Sending array as a parameter allows hackers to push its own data very easily into your parameter. That's why passing array is not advisable, but possible.

Comment: Use volley ! Saves you loads of code + time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Example:

Like if we have our data in arraylist to upload on server, Yo can send it in this way

```
JsonArray _array = new JsonArray()

for(i = 0; i< _arraylist.size(); i++){
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();

obj.put(_array.list.get(i).getValue);

_array.put(obj);
}

}
```